# How do I set up a namespaces sort order in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, namespaces, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I have a project with classes with folders structure:

- entities
- models
- services
- controllers
- components
- modules
- и т.д.

For now *PhpStorm* allows to sort imports alphabetically (ascending order), but I don't satisfied of  it. No matter why.

I want that if I click  "ReformatCode" or "RefactorCode" or namespace Auto Import, *PhpStorm* do sort namespaces as I want. How do I do that? For example: do order like in the list above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible. The only two options are sorting alphabetically and sorting by the import length.

You might wanna submit this as a feature request, but to be honest with you, I don't think there's a great chance it's going to be implemented any time soon.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=WI

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think there's no sense in trying to ask of this feature :))